# Firebase Cloud Functions : How to split a function into multiple files?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Firebase cloud functions: TypeScrip
How to split a function into multiple files?

I want to use admin and searchClient in different files.

**Index.ts**

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const searchClient = algoliasearch(env.algolia.appid, env.algolia.apikey);

....

exports.query = require('./query');
exports.products = require('./products');
```

**query.ts**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import {searchClient} from "./index";

const requestIndex = searchClient.initIndex("allRequests");
```

**products.ts**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import {admin} from "./index";

const firestoreDb = admin.firestore();
```

Comment: please check this [article](https://jsmobiledev.com/article/functions-multiple-files/) which might help

Answer (score 1):

In order to use admin and searchClient in any other place of your project, you first need to export them from the index.ts file:

**index.ts**

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
export { admin }

const searchClient = algoliasearch(env.algolia.appid, env.algolia.apikey);
export { searchClient }
```

Then, you are able to import them into your query.ts and products.ts files :

**query.ts**

```
import { searchClient } from "./index";
```

**products.ts**

```
import { admin } from "./index";
```